# Wordpress add pages with category to category archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that category archives are intended for posts.
But due to some requirements, I also need to assign a category to some pages.
And need to add those pages to category archives.
Does someone know if it's possible?
p.s I already managed to assign a category to page.

Comment: you should be able to use the pre_get_posts filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Stender.
This solved my issue:

```
function sbt_exclude_category($query){
    if ( $query->is_page('slug') && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type',  'any' );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','sbt_exclude_category');
```